# Alternative Session/static vars ASP.NET/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session-variables, static-variables

I'd like to know if there is a valid Session or static in .NET environment.
What I need is a variable to store some data that maintans its value, accessible through all ASP.NET pages / C# forms **but not unique for all users that use the application**.

Comment: Have you even googled for .net and session? Look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, I searched into the web but i didn't find what I need. Maybe I didn't used the right words. Yes, principarly I use C# for Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 2):

Then your answer would likely be Application Cache. Look at System.Web.Caching

Since there is some discussion about lifetime of the cache object, you can set it. The user was not specific, however in how long this has to live. Between application recycles? during the lifetime of a single instance, does it need to be between instances.  Cache will work for the most simple requirement.

Comment: That is not guaranteed to maintain its value, is it?

Comment: For the lifetime of the application it is. it will not work between instances by default.

Comment: The application cache maintains its value unless you have set it to expire (sliding or absolute), or your application restarts, or you remove the cache entry through some other mechanism.

Comment: +1 ok, i see that. But the question also implies not unique for all users and the cache is

Comment: Cache is most certainly NOT unique for all users. He says that specifically he wants it that way.

Comment: It is guarenteed to maintain its state within one instance of iis. It can be configured to do so also in a iis farm. It is only applicable for iis hosts.

Answer (score 2):

I would think you are looking for Application State rather than Application Cache.
Application State would work the same way like session state but would be shared between all sessions.

Sample usage:

```
 Application["Message"] = "Welcome to my Website";
```

More information:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87316/A-walkthrough-to-Application-State

Comment: Does not answer the question, as op specifically mentions winforms

Comment: The question mentions ASP.NET, there is also ASP.NET tag on it

Comment: Yes and your answer is then correct. However op mentions c# forms, which could be winforms. Win forms do not have access to the toolset you describe

Comment: But the Application State shares the value for all users. I looking something that I can access from all pages but different for each user that access to the website. For example to store System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

Comment: I see in this case in ASP.NET you can use Session state, the usage is the same, you'd just use Session instead of Application. If you mean windows Forms you will have usually one person using your application so it is usually not an issue. Unless you want to provide ability so that multiple users on one computer have their own profiles. Then you can look into local storage.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the application cache? it is shared for all users throughout your application, accessible from all pages, and not unique per user.

please see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) for more details on how to use the caching API

Comment: If you need to maintain these values beyond the lifetime of an instance of you application, you may have to resort to a persistent data storage instead of sessions, cache, etc. i.e. file or db.

Comment: Not instead of sessions. You can easily configure the session provider to use persistent storage. Mixing apples and bananas ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try handling this with an Application-scoped variable.

First in your Global.asax file, add the following:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    [Other Stuff Already Here Omitted]
    Application["MyVariable"] = "My Default value";
}
```

Then on any page, you can access this:

```
var myVar = Application["MyVariable"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may expose a class as Static. That'll make it available across all Sessions, but restricted to that Application instance.

Comment: It's your prerrogative, and feel free to do so. My own personal criteria is that downvotes may be applied to unclear or useless answers, not because of a personal preference on methodology - and at the end of the day a Pattern is just another tool (often misused, according to my own experience), to be put to work or not according to the situation. Specific to the the OP's scenario, a Static class would cover his needs and have the least number of 'moving parts' - thus, useful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The exists no ".Net environment" on that level. Your .Net code gets runtime restrictions from the host also. 
Lets define two hosts (there are more):
IIS and "simply main exe".

For IIS hosted code, you are operating in an environment where the host is creating a thread (or rather allocating one) and executing your code on this thread. The host itself defines when and if to reset the process. You cannot, or rather should not, assume anything about which process or thread is executing your code. This gets enhanced when you talk about iis in a farm.

For simple main code in an exe, the operating system creates the process and initial first thread and the sets the execution pointer to the first statement in the main function.

"static" maintains state throughout the lifetime of the owning process, that is a guarantee given to you by .Net.

"Session" is specific implementation to handle much more than static properties.

I would recommend a refinement of the question where you also describe your host. For iis, the answer could be AppFabric cache.

Hope this helps